# Convert a list in Scala to Python list or dataFrame

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, py4j

I have a 2d list in Scala called `dataList` and I want to convert it to a Pandas `DataFrame`.

```
val dataList: List[List[Int]] = tempData.toList
```

If I want to print `dataList`, everything works fine and the type of object in Python is

```
<class 'py4j.java_gateway.JavaObject'>
```

As far as I know, I have to use `py4j` to have access to collections in Python. However, I think I have to use a nested loop to access each element of `dataList` and then put in a `DataFrame`. Is there any smarter way to directly convert it to `DataFrame` or a python list and then `DataFrame`?

I'm using Zeppelin 0.5.5

Comment: Since I'm using Zeppelin, yes!

Comment: Then add `Apache-Spark` to question's tags, this question might be useful for someone else in the future or perhaps someone had this inquietude before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convert your Scala List to a Java List first (using converters), PySpark should be able to auto convert it to a Python list.

In a Scala cell:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

// Sample of what I assume your "dataList" looks like
val dataList: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6))
// Convert to java.util.List
val javaDataList: java.util.List[java.util.List[Int]] =
  dataList.map(_.asJava).asJava
// Place in Zeppelin context for %pyspark cell access
z.put("dataList", javaDataList)
```

In a separate cell for Python:

```
%pyspark
# Read from Zeppelin context
dataList = z.get("dataList")
print dataList
```

You could also conceivably convert your Scala list to a (Spark) DataFrame first, hand that over to Python, and then call "toPandas()" to get a Pandas DataFrame. I wouldn't recommend it though, since you'd just be parallelizing the data, and then unparallelizing it again (when you call toPandas()).